# Partly deactivate xaml Styler plugin (at LineBreak MultiBinding cleanup)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, string-formatting

I'm using xaml-Styler Plugin on VS2015. So far I didn't had any problems.

Now I have the problem, that the styler removes linebreaks (I use HTML encoded characters).

xaml (simplified)

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}&#13;Min X:   {1:F3}; Max X:   {2:F3}">
            <Binding Path="Area.Name" ... />
            <Binding Path="Area.MinX" ... />
            <Binding Path="Area.MaxX" ... />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

after Pressing Save, the xaml styler automatically makes this (html character is removed and LineBreak inserted:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}
Min X:   {1:F3}; Max X:   {2:F3}">
            <Binding Path="Area.Name" ... />
            <Binding Path="Area.MinX" ... />
            <Binding Path="Area.MaxX" ... />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

then the text is displayed at one line.

I'm not happy with using html encoded characters at all. Is there maybe a better (simple) way to format strings with linebreaks in a MultiBinding?

For this simple formatting I don't want to use a MultiValueConverter, because it is only an informative string...

If I could tell xaml styler don't style this part/line I would be happy, but didn't found the possibility or a property in options of xaml styler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the hex representation of the LineFeed character (char 10) : `&#x0a;` to get a line break :

```
<TextBlock>
       <TextBlock.Text>
           <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} &#x0a; Min X:   {1:F3}&#x0a; Max X:   {2:F3}">
               <Binding Path="Area.Name" ... />
               <Binding Path="Area.MinX" ... />
               <Binding Path="Area.MaxX" ... />
           </MultiBinding>
       </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: But why do you want to save it like that?

Comment: I'm sorry about wrong comment yesterday. My test was incorrect! using LF &#x0a; or CR &#x0d; instead of &#10; or &#13; works fine with xaml styler and will not been removed! Thank you.